# Node state tracking / logging using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm exploring potential use cases for neo4j, and I find that the relationship model is great, but I'm curious if the database can support something along the lines of a business transaction log.

For instance, a video rental store:

- Customer A rents Video A on 01/01/2014
- Customer A returns Video A on 01/20/2014
- Customer B rents Video A on 01/25/2014
- Customer B returns video A on 02/15/2014
- Customer C rents Video A on 03/10/2014
- etc...

The business requirement would be to track all rental transaction relationships relating to the Video A node.

This seems to be technically possible. Would one create a new relationship for every time that a new rental occurs? Are there better ways to approach this? Is this a misuse of the technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice! This is the exact use case that led me to develop [FlockData](http://github.com/monowai/flockdata.org) (github link). FD uses Neo4J to track event type activity against a domain document (Rental in your example). Then use Tags to create Nodes that represent Meta Data associated with the domain doc (Movie/Person). You have an event node for each change in state of the Rental. Couple of graphs over here on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/company/3361595) showing "User Created", "User Approved" and "User Audited".

FD uses 3 databases to achieve its goals - Neo4j for the network of relationships, KV store for the bulky data (Redis or Riak) and ElasticSearch to let users find their Business Context Document (the Rental) via free text.

In terms of your specific question exercise caution with nodes that have a lot of relationships. Checkout [this article](http://blog.nigelsmall.com/2012/09/modelling-dates-in-neo4j.html) on modelling dates. Peter Neubauer has a similar article somewhere in the Neo4j docs.

Comment: +1 just create a rental node that you connect to your customer, your video(s) and perhaps a time-tree.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at it depending on what you're trying to get out of it.  If you're looking to develop a recommendation engine, or see the relationships between users and/or movies, a graphDB is a pretty natural solution.  If you're looking at tracking the state changes of Video A over time, a Temporal database is modeled for that (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database).  For a straight up transactional system, a traditional relational database will work easily. Personally, I think you'll have better options with a graphDB.  In your example, you would have 3 consumer nodes, 1 video node, 3 relationships of type :RENTS and two of :RETURNS.  You'd want to make sure that your property model supports the same user re-renting the same movie (store the date in an array, not a single value).  Just some thoughts...

Comment: If Customer A rents Video A again, could I create a new relationship of type :RENTS? Is that supported?

Comment: hrm - made a full comment - only the first part stayed... anyway, I thought that you can only connect two nodes with the same type of relationship once (e.g. you can only have one (user:User)-[:RENTS]->(video:Video) for a specific user/video combo.  I'll let other more knowledgeable provide solutions for needing this kind of solution.